# Windows 10 per-app audio balance

Tags: windows-10, audio

Back in the olden days, the volume control used to include a balance slider so the balance could be adjusted by application, as in the image below.

[image]

Now it seems I can only change the balance by device rather than by application - this means I can't, for instance, put Discord chat audio in my left ear while listening to Youtube with my right.

Is there a way to get that balance slider back, or otherwise enable per-application balance adjustment?

Comment: Windows never contained such a feature. You may be remembering the volume mixer from XP (and earlier). It had the balance slider. Not for applications though, but for inputs/outputs.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd used it in the past to move app audio around... I've certainly used, for instance, video in one ear and comms in the other. Perhaps that was something I set in the applications themselves. Either way, it should be so simply and obvious to have as standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is now a Windows "feature" and you can't modify the Windows Volume Mixer, but you can accomplish what you're trying to do with 3rd party apps.

NirSoft's SoundVolumeView (free) and Power Mixer (paid) will do it.

1. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html
2. https://www.actualsolution.com/download/

See here for how to use SoundVolumeView via command line. You may need to run the command(s) for your setup at each login as a startup item:

https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/set-audio-balance-command-line.html

You could also set up a few batch files for quick-switch settings if you didn't want to click around in the GUI.

Comment: Just for reference and nostalgia - it was called Volume Control in Win98 and WinXP. You can see them here :)


[Windows 98 Volume Control](https://i.postimg.cc/G2yhDYJs/volume-mixer-win98.png),

[Windows XP Volume Control](https://i.postimg.cc/zDhVHm0P/volume-mixer-win-XP.jpg)

Comment: Yup, those were good days. I really don't understand why they removed such a simple and useful function.

Comment: Have downloaded the Power Mixer trial, will give it a go. Looks like it'll do what I want it to, cheers!